# How to generate pretty print docs while using spring cloud contract

Tags: spring-restdocs, spring-cloud-contract

Without introducing spring cloud contract, I customized the configuration of restdocs as below,

```
  @Rule
  public JUnitRestDocumentation restDocumentation = new JUnitRestDocumentation();


  protected WebTestClient http;
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext context;

  /**
   * setup.
   */
  @Before
  public void before() {
    this.http = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(context)
        .configureClient()
        .baseUrl("http://theserver")
        .filter(WebTestClientRestDocumentation
            .documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation)
            .operationPreprocessors()
            .withRequestDefaults(prettyPrint())
            .withResponseDefaults(prettyPrint())
        )
        .build();
  }
```

However while using spring restdocs and cloud contract together, I have to use the annotation to enable rest docs and cloud contract,

```
@AutoConfigureRestDocs(uriHost = "theserver", uriPort = 80)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public abstract class BaseTest {
```

Any advice how to generate pretty print docs while generating cloud contract stubs?

Comment: Maybe you should migrate the setup to `org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsMockMvcConfigurationCustomizer` ? However it looks fishy to me. Let's ask https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384297/andy-wilkinson for help

Comment: Hi, I know this is old but I am facing the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66942224/spring-autoconfigurerestdocs-additional-configuration. I really want to find a way to do it with AutoConfigureRestDocs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is not to use the `@AutoConfigureRestDocs` but use the API to pass to `WebTestClientRestDocumentation.documentationConfiguration(...)` the `.snippets().withAdditionalDefaults(new WireMockSnippet())` line. That way by default you will start producing WireMock snippets and all of your previous configuration will not be discarded.