# Spring AutoConfigureRestDocs additional configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restdocs

I am generating documentation using `Spring REST` docs and I am using the new annotation `@AutoConfigureRestDocs` instead of explicitly defining in the `@BeforeEach` method. The below test is currently working.

```
@WebMvcTest(PayrollController.class)
@AutoConfigureRestDocs
class PayrollControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void testHello() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/payroll/hello"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string("hello world"));
    }
}
```

But now I need to pretty print my response and I don't want to do that in every method. As per spring documentation, there is the option to customize further using `RestDocsMockMvcConfigurationCustomizer`. I did create a bean of that type as per below:

```
     @WebMvcTest(PayrollController.class)
        @AutoConfigureRestDocs
        class PayrollControllerTest {
        
            @Configuration
            static class RestDocsConfiguration {
                @Bean
                public RestDocsMockMvcConfigurationCustomizer restDocsMockMvcConfigurationCustomizer() {
                    return configurer -> configurer.operationPreprocessors().withResponseDefaults(Preprocessors.prettyPrint());
                }
            }
         @Autowired
         private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
        @Test
        void testHello() throws Exception {
            this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/payroll/hello"))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(content().string("hello world"));
        }
}
```

But now all my tests are failing and are returning 404 not found. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: It's not clear why that would happen from what you've shared thus far. Can you update your question with a (link to a) [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Hello I have included a minimal reproducible example. Hope that can help. Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't appear to be complete. You haven't shared the controller that has a request mapping for `/api/payroll/hello`. I also can't tell what version of Spring Boot and any other dependencies you're using. Can you share a complete project that contains just enough code to reproduce the problem? Something generated using https://start.spring.io would be an ideal starting point.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson This is the link for the complete project (minimal reproducible) https://github.com/ashley-s/rest-docs-sample. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by your use of `@Configuration`. As described in the [Spring Boot reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.4/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config), when your test class has a nested `@Configuration` class it is used instead of your application's primary configuration. You should use `@TestConfiguration` on your nested `RestDocsConfiguration` class instead.

Comment: Thank a lot for your help. It works fine now.